# Creating a plugin for Sublime Text 3 in a language other than Python

Tags: python, c++, c, sublimetext3

I want to create a plugin for Sublime Text 3 in another language, say, in C++ or C or any other compiled language. Is it possible? Preferably without any Python code or libraries at all except the ones that's already installed with Sublime Text3.

If not, is there any workaround? The thing here is that I want the plugin to be a compiled language. I'm aware about Python ".pyc" files but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you consider writing a C library and loading it using Python's FFI...?

Comment: What kind of functionality will your plugin have? A lot of commonly implemented plugin features ( *which utilize event listeners, text regions, window & view settings, etc.* ) are handled via the [**native python API**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

Comment: Some plugins like [**ColorPicker**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorPicker) make use of [**external processes**](https://github.com/weslly/ColorPicker/tree/master/lib) for implementing features that are non-standard, such as GUIs, but still have a considerable amount of `python` code ( *which is required to tie the external processes to the previously mentioned native features* ).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to make a Sublime Text plugin with absolutely zero python code. However, you can call a binary application from the python plugin and put all of your logic in there.

For example, [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) does part of its work in python, but calls out to binaries such as [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/) and [ruby -wc](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/) for the actual linting of the file.